# 1 JSON object, 2 queries, 2 tables

Tags: php, sql, json

Here is my simple query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM donations Order By userid"; 
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  $json[] = $row;
}

$data['data'] = $json;
```

I use it to display all data from the 'donations' in a table. Fields are: `userid,date,amount`.

In that same table, I'd like to add `firstname` and `lastname` of corresponding `userid` which are stored in `mymembers` table. The condition should be `WHERE donations.userid = mymembers.id`.

I need help adding that condition for every row resulting from the `$sql` query.

Answer (score 0):

Use join and change query to

```
 SELECT * FROM donations
    INNER JOIN mymembers on (donations.userid = mymembers.id)
    Order By donations.userid
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ranjeet!

Comment: @s_b The normal way to thank someone is to Upvote their answer and if it is a complete solution to Accept the answer